# Redis With No TTL

Tags: redis

Here is a snapshot of my redis settings

```
Total Keys  Keys with Expiry    Keys without Expiry
60Lacs      20Lacs              40Lacs
```

Is there any method provided by Redis:

1. Automatically set a TTL of 1 day on any key created by an application that doesn't specify a TTL
2. Remove All existing keys with no TTL

Answer (score 2):

As far as question one - No, Redis does not provide a global TTL setting.  The TTL has to be set on a per key basis.  There are some ways you could script a solution but there is nothing built in.  If you are concerned about the memory usage, look in to your configurations and modify the max-memory settings.  See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25618045/can-i-set-global-ttl-in-redis) for more information.

As far as question two - This script in Python is a basic example of how to iterate over the keys and delete anything without a TTL, you should build on it for your needs.  Important information about making this performant can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22255589/get-all-keys-in-redis-database-with-python).

```
import redis
r = redis.StrictRedis(host='localhost', port=6379)

for key in r.scan_iter("*"):
    ttl = r.ttl(key)
    if ttl == -1:
        r.delete(key)
```

Comment: runnung a scan on production ? it will lock the db

Comment: That is why I added the disclaimer - "you should build on it for your needs. Important information about making this performant can be found in this answer."

Comment: Actually scans are ok for production:  https://redis.io/commands/scan . "Since these commands allow for incremental iteration, returning only a small number of elements per call, they can be used in production"